# Fitting a linear model

Tags: r, statistics, curve-fitting

I have a data frame that looks like

```
> t
          Institution Subject Class       ML1     ML1SD
aPhysics0           A Physics     0 0.8730469 0.3329205
aPhysics1           A Physics     1 0.8471074 0.3598839
aPhysics2           A Physics     2 0.8593750 0.3476343
aPhysics3           A Physics     3 0.8875000 0.3159806
aPhysics4           A Physics     4 0.7962963 0.4027512
```

And I want to fit a linear function to `ML1` against `Class`, but when I call

```
> lm(ML1 ~ Class, data=t)
```

I get:

```
Call:
lm(formula = ML1 ~ Class, data = t)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       Class1       Class2       Class3       Class4  
    0.87305     -0.02594     -0.01367      0.01445     -0.07675
```

Which I don't really understand, because it looks like it is giving me multiple gradient values for each value of `Class`, but there are 5 `Class` values (0-4). But what I want is a single intercept and a single gradient value.

Also, when I call `lm` with `weights = 1/ML1SD^2` it does not change any of the values.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that the complete dataset you're modelling? There's only one observation for each class?

Comment: Try `lm(ML1 ~ as.numeric(as.character(Class)),data=t)`, but are you sure that `Class` is a ratio scale?

Comment: For your weights , What is ML1SD?

Comment: @alexwhan these are the mean values for ~200 observations

Comment: @agstudy they are the standard deviations from the mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Class` is seen as a `categorical variable` to `lm`. I would suppose that your `Class` is a factor.

And the result of the regression is correct in the sense that the estimates are corresponding to 4 classes. This is because, by default, the first level (`0`, in your case) is taken as the *reference* level, and all the estimates you obtain are with respect to the reference. That is, `mean(Class1) - mean(Class0)` is equal to `-0.02594`.

If you don't want categorical variable on `Class` and you want to model it as a continuous variable, then, you must convert `factor` to `numeric` (or `integer`) type by doing: `df$Class <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Class))`. Then, you get:

```
> lm(ML1 ~ Class, data=df)

Call:
lm(formula = ML1 ~ Class, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        Class  
    0.87529     -0.01131
```

But are you sure `Class` is a continuous variable?

**Edit:** The `weights` parameter does have an effect. It performs a weighted linear least squares regression. You can see that for the `categorical variable` when you do `summary(.)`:

```
summary( ML1 ~ factor(Class), data = df)
```

But in your case, the categorical variables have only one value.

Let me illustrate with another example:

```
set.seed(45)
# meaningless data
df <- data.frame(x=runif(10), y=rep(1:3, c(4,3,3)))

summary(lm(x ~ factor(y), data=df))
# without weights 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
# (Intercept)  0.39256    0.09481   4.141  0.00435 **
# factor(y)2  -0.09999    0.14482  -0.690  0.51216   
# factor(y)3  -0.14433    0.14482  -0.997  0.35214   


summary(lm(x ~ factor(y), data=df, weights=1/y))
# with weights
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  0.39256    0.07148   5.492 0.000914 ***
# factor(y)2  -0.09999    0.13687  -0.731 0.488798    
# factor(y)3  -0.14433    0.15983  -0.903 0.396528
```